# Rails4 children objects won't save when parent updated even with autosave: true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following relationships defined in a Rails4 app:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, autosave: true, dependent: destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children, allow_destroy: true
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, autosave: true
end
```

In `ParentsController#update`, I call `@parent.update_attributes(parent_params)`, and changes that are passed on to the child objects via `children_attributes` hash are not saved at all.

I've tried calling `@parent.save`, and still, nothing happens. When I finally call `@parent.children.map(&:save)`, then finally the children objects get updated.

I want to avoid calling save on every child object. Isn't this what `autosave: true` is supposed to do? Am I missing something here?

Comment: can you please share your controller logic where you are updating the parent but the children attributes are not being updated ?

Comment: Is this `dependent: destroy` ok?

Comment: @Ajay the controller calls `@parent.update_attributes(parent_params)`. Using pry, I'm able to go in and see that nothing actually gets saved (no SQL UPDATE) until I call `save` directly on the children. Neither the parent nor the children have any errors, and when I call `save` directly, it works.

Comment: am not sure what you have coded in your controller. If in your case with parent_params only parent attributes are assigned then it's not going to touch your child attributes during parent update.

Comment: The children attributes are assigned properly, but the child object is never saved automatically. I can tell because when I call `@parent.update_attributes(parent_params)` followed by `@parent.children.map(&:save)`, a SQL UPDATE is generated and I can verify that the children objects have the correct new values.

Comment: Please, search at rails console for `Unpermitted parameters:` on update.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Alejandro, but the strong parameters are actually making it through. From a pry breakpoint at the very beginning of `ParentsController#update`, I can inspect the entire hash. The issue seems to be that the property I'm setting is changed through a custom setter, and so AR is not picking up that it's been changed?

Comment: Can you post your `parent_params` method.

Comment: `def parent_params
      params.require(:parent).permit!
    end`